# Zoom An Entire View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an app im working on. The main view controller has a keypad ( like on a safe door). I want the user to tap on the numbers pad and i want the whole view to zoom in. This is not a UIImageView. I know how to zoom an image/imageView. I want to have a super small set of numbers/number pad, and a super small textfield, then when it zooms in, those two UI elements will be big. I would like to have this done via button press! 
Thanks in advance. I have no code to provide! Sorry, And Thanks :D

Comment: As one possible solution take a look at using your view's 'transform' property to scale the view. Hard to say if this is what you want without knowing more about the effect you want and how your view is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to just make an imageview, zoom this to your desired size, then hide it and "replace it" by the real number pad. To do that just have the number pad hidden at the beginning and visible, once the image view reaches its final size and disappears (just hide it then)

To the user it all looks as if the "number pad" will zoom - which is actually your image of the number pad.

Also to have only one View to hide/unhide just put your all your keys of the number pad and whatever else on one container view.

To get the image to be zoomed, just make a screenshot and cut out your zoomable image area with some kind of Photoshop tool.

By the way, I would expect your idea of a zooming number pad will surely be a nice animation in your app!

Comment: Also, you could make frame of the view that has to be zoomed bigger when button is pressed.